# Why is my iPhoto Library size so much bigger than its contents?

Tags: photos.app

I've stopped using iPhoto and want to extract my Originals and trash the library itself. After I pulled out my originals, I noticed that they're nowhere near the 8GB iPhoto Library size Finder is reporting. So I checked the package contents, and selecting everything including hidden files, the total size is only 1GB. I copied everything out to be sure, also 1GB. `du -hs` from Terminal, also 1GB.

Any thoughts why Finder thinks it's taking up 8GB of space?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your iPhoto Library and right-click on it and select "Show Contents".
Then sort by List (Command+2).
Then go to Finder-View--Show View Options (Command+J) and select "Calculate all sizes"

It will count up all the folder/file sizes and you can see what is taking up space where.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but somewhere along the way, Finder decided to recalculate the package size and came up with the correct amount. It looks like the size calculation was cached somewhere.